# Introducing a "sub-part" within the Book Class

Tags: book-design, parts

Is there a straightforward way to introduce a "sub-part" within the Book Class (between "part" and "chapter")? Here is an illustration. Suppose I write a long book discussing the natural sciences, and that Part III will deal with mathematics. Part III is to be organized as follows:

Part III. Mathematics

```
    Chapter 1. Overview

A. Pure Mathematics
    Chapter 2. Arithmetic
    Chapter 3. Geometry ...

B. Applied Mathematics
    Chapter 7. Math in Physics
    Chapter 8. Math in Biology ...
```

Comment: Is there some reasons, that you doesn't use "book for "part" and ˇpart" for "subpart"? At least `memoir` has defined '\book` as possible division level.

Comment: @Zarko That would involve a significant change if the OP is using `book` as the class, would it not?

Comment: Take a look at `titlesec` which lets you do this, if I remember correctly. If you get stuck, post a Minimum Working Example so that people can help with the code.

Comment: @cfr, I do not see big difference, if you use existed division and only change the names/numbers of appearing top two levels (if you like so) or you define new division levels (for example as you suggested with `titlesec` which is by the way great package and right tool to do this). To my opinion, existed division levels is well deliberate and invention of new division levels can cause unexpected complications on the end.

Comment: And how would a subpart stick in this example? It is mentioned nowhere. Apart from that,  you  can take a look at the `titlesec` documentation, §3.9, *Creating new levels and changing the class*.

Comment: @arko: It might be meaningful, by the fact that the class of the section level would have to change, and the semantic point of view is important too. A subpart title that stays on a page of its own is not the same, semantically, as a chapter.

Comment: @Zarko Changing from `book` to `memoir` is a substantive change. Of course, it depends on what else is going on. But switching to `memoir` is unlikely to be trivial in the majority of cases.

Comment: @cfr, now I see miss understanding. I do not suggest to change document class `book` with `memoir`, I mentioned it as example (with which I'm familiar) where mentioned division exist. If `book` doesn't provide this level of division, my comment can be miss leading.

Comment: @Zarko Oh, I see. No, `book` does not provide that level of division. The OP would have to switch class or use `titlesec` or equivalent to create it (in which case, it might as well be called `sub-part`).

Comment: @cfr Thank you both. The titlesec suggestion solves my problem.

Comment: Hi Bill, can you add an answer with the code the worked for you? Thanks.